# Why are my daffodils putting out flower buds in January?

Tags: flowering, bulbs, overwintering, daffodils

Why are my dwarf double yellow daffodils putting out flower buds? It's January, and they usually start that in March. They could get damaged by cold and wildlife during winter. Anyone know what is going on? The winter has been about average, except for the roller coaster temperatures (warm one day, freezing the next).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you had unseasonably warm weather in the past few weeks? (we have down here in Texas). Unseasonably warm weather will often 'trick' plants into producing new leaves and/or flowers early. The real problem occurs if there's a frost which kills new buds/growth (I suspect daffodils are less prone to that than, say, fruit trees).

Comment: Any unseasonably warm weather hasn't lasted long, but it has been odd. It was 13 degrees Fahrenheit one day, then a couple of days later it is sixty five. It is supposed to get below 15 tonight.